# Get creation time of keyspace in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to write a script which will delete old keyspaces in Cassandra. But I am stuck on how to define when certain keyspace was created, not sure even if it is possible, I was trying to google it, but unfortunately found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I can think of for doing this is:

```
select keyspace_name, writetime(durable_writes) from system_schema.keyspaces
```

but this is the last write time of the keyspace rather than the create time. So, if you alter the keyspace the time will change.